# How to bind data in table in asp using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

**  HI friends .I try to bind the data in table using jquery.But is not working and the value is not showing .I am a beginner in jquery.
Can you modify my code. And can you say which is more good and fast to bind values asp  or jquery**

```
<script src="Data_Table.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        bind(res);
    });

    function bind(res) {
       url = "XXXX.aspx/XXXXXX";


       var rows = JSON.parse(res.d);
       if (res.d != "[]") {
           var data = [];
           $.each(rows, function (index, row) {
               data.push([++index
               , row.Id
               , row.date
               , row.shift
               , row.Door
               , row.Green
               , row.Time
               , row.Cycle
               , row.Fault
               ]);
           });
           table = $("#XXX").DataTable({
               destroy: true,
               data: data,
               deferRender: true,
               paging: true,
           });

       } else {
           alert("No Record Found");
       }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where is `res` defined? Any errors in browser dev tools console?

Comment: Please provide error and code